# How to get the index of randomElement

Tags: swift

I want to know how I can get the index of an array in Swift if I use randomElement.

Example :

I've an array from a JSON file. After each click on a button, I want to change the label by a value from the array.
I want to looping through the array for print the value and delete this after the display. The problem is I don't see how I get the current value to delete her.

```
if let rand = myArray.randomElement() {
    myLabel.text = rand.question       
}
```

I've seen more options to make a random in array but with  after reading some articles for Swift 4.2, the best practice is to use **randomElement()**.

Comment: get a random index instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to get a random index

```
if let index = myArray.indices.randomElement() {
    myLabel.text = myArray[index].question 
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I've add `myArray.remove(at: index)` after and that's work!

Thank you!

Comment: @Galnash `remove(at:)` returns the element that was removed, so you can write: `myLabel.text = myArray.remove(at: index).question`

Comment: @Galnash Actually, on second thought, I'm not sure how much I like that. It might make sense if this was first assigned to an intermediate variable `let removedElement = ...`. Not a fan of having this statement have 2 effects (removal from array, assignment to `myLabel.text`)

Comment: @Alexander I've change this in my code don't worry!